not able to run spring boot project with zuul dependency on spring boot version 2.2.2.RELEASE
We are implementing spring cloud zuul proxy in our application. Problem is that we are not able to run it using spring boot parent version 2.2.2.RELEASE.
Everything is working fine with spring boot parent version 1.5.22.RELEASE (which we used to use earlier). Lately, we are updating our applications to run on higher spring boot version.
for reference below is the pom.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <!--<version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>-->
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.wgits.crbt</groupId>
    <artifactId>zuul-proxy2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>zuul-proxy2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

We are getting below error response:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:196)
    at com.wgits.crbt.ZuulProxyApplication.main(ZuulProxyApplication.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more

Issue resolves if we comment higher spring boot parent version and uncomment lower one.
What should we do to maintain our application works on higher version.
Tried including commons logging dependency also.. but didn't worked.

Does this answer your question? apache.commons.logging classNotFound even after added dependency to Maven

@J. Doe, Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul has been deprecated for many years now. Please do not use it. We suggest you use Spring Cloud Gateway instead.
